# Shortcut in Python for repetitive actions with variables?

Tags: python, performance, object, action, shortcut

I was wondering if there is a way to express the following code in a shorter way using Python. There is `placedWall`, `placedFlyer`, `placedSpring`, and `placedDiamonds`. And, `placedWallList`, `placedFlyerList`, `placedSpringList`, and `placedDiamondsList`. I want to do this because I am going to add more objects with the same repetitive actions, which will make my code unnecessarily long.

```
for placedWall in placedWallList:
    if placedWall.rect.collidepoint(mousePos):
        placedsprites.remove(placedWall)
        placedWallList.remove(placedWall)
for placedFlyer in placedFlyerList:
    if placedFlyer.rect.collidepoint(mousePos):
        placedsprites.remove(placedFlyer)
        placedFlyerList.remove(placedFlyer)
for placedSpring in placedSpringList:
    if placedSpring.rect.collidepoint(mousePos):
        placedsprites.remove(placedSpring)
        placedSpringList.remove(placedSpring)
for placedDiamonds in placedDiamondsList:
    if placedDiamonds.rect.collidepoint(mousePos):
        placedsprites.remove(placedDiamonds)
        placedDiamondsList.remove(placedDiamonds)
```

Comment: Have you tried a function? EDIT: Nevermind, jonrsharpe's answer is better. (and more beautiful :))

Comment: Yes, write a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to put the lists all together into one dictionary `{'walls': […], 'flyers': […], …}` and try this:

```
for group, items in placed_objects.items():
    placed_objects[group] = [x for x in items if not x.collidepoint(mousePos)]
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for (I wasn't clear enough in my question). Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Just iterate over the lists:

```
for item_list in (placedWallList, placedFlyerList, placedSpringList, placedDiamondsList):
    for item in item_list:
        if item.rect.collidepoint(mousePos):
            placedsprites.remove(item)
            item_list.remove(item)
```

However, note that the last line alters the length of a list *while iterating over it*, which is a pretty bad idea! This will cause the item *after* the one that was just removed to be skipped, and may cause an `IndexError` at the end of the list.

Comment: You might want to put all "placed" items in a `dict` call "placed", and the keys called "wallList", etc... as well

Comment: @GerardvanHelden it's not clear what you're suggesting, sorry.

Comment: Why not use reversed?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I was hoping the OP might figure that out on their own!

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I think that might be their next question, why does remove ...!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Since the items are so similar, I'd put them in a dict, so you can write `for name,item_list in placed.items(): ...`. But that might be just a matter of taste here :)

Comment: @GerardvanHelden but then how would you use the `name`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe only to add items to the dict.